# How to run a jquery function in first click and another function in second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a html menu that work with jquery functions. when some one click on a parent menu item  it is showing the sub item and if there is another sub items (childs) those are showing if the user click first sub item and when he move his mouse out of the parent item every sub item and child items are not displaying because of this is little bit confusing to the user I am trying to change the mouse leave event to click event.

```
<div style="margin-top: 200px; width: 140px; text-align: left;">
                    <div>
                        <a href="#Home" onclick="close_this()" class="lmenu">Home</a>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <a href="#AboutUs" onclick="load_contents('aboutus.php', 400, '')" class="lmenu">About Us</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="lmenu parent">
                        <div>
                            <a href="#" class="lmenu">Our Services</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="subperent">
                            <a href="#">
                                Event Management
                            </a>
                            <div class="chilld" onclick="load_contents('eventmngmnt.php', 400, 'categories.php')">
                                <a class="lmenu" href="#">
                                    Categories
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="chilld" onclick="load_contents('providingfac.php', 800, '')">
                                <a class="lmenu" href="#">
                                    Providing Facilities
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="subperent">
                            <a href="#">
                                Rental
                            </a>
                            <div class="chilld">
                                <a class="lmenu" href="#" onclick="load_contents('avequipments.php', 850, '')">
                                    AVEquipments
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="chilld">
                                <a class="lmenu" href="#" onclick="load_contents('otherservices.php', 850, '')">
                                    Other Services
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="subperent">
                            <a href="#">
                                Exhibition Stalls 
                            </a>
                            <div class="chilld">
                                <a class="lmenu" href="#standard_stall" onclick="load_contents('standardstalls.php', 600, '')">
                                    Standard Stall
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="chilld">
                                <a class="lmenu" href="#designed_stall" onclick="load_contents('designedstalls.php', 600, '')">
                                    Designed Stalls
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div style="clear: both"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="lmenu parent">
                        <div>
                            <a href="#" class="lmenu">Gallery</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="subperent">
                            <a class="lmenu" onclick="load_contents('gallery.php', 600, '')" href="#">
                                Events & Confferance
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="subperent">
                            <a class="lmenu" onclick="load_contents('gallery_stalls.php', 600, '')" href="#">
                                Stalls
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

then I'm using this jquery script to view and hide sub items and child items of the menu.

```
var $sub_itmes;
$(".parent").on({
    click: function() {
        $sub_itmes = $('.subperent', this);
        $sub_itmes.css({
            "display": "block",
        });
        $sub_itmes.animate({
            "opacity": 1
        });
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $sub_itmes = $('.subperent', this);
        $sub_itmes.css({
            "display": "none",
        });
        $sub_itmes.animate({
            "opacity": 0
        });
    }
});

$(".subperent").on({
    click: function() {
        $sub_itmes = $('.chilld', this);
        $sub_itmes.css({
            "display": "block",
        });
        $sub_itmes.animate({
            "opacity": 1
        });
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $sub_itmes = $('.chilld', this);
        $sub_itmes.css({
            "display": "none",
        });
        $sub_itmes.animate({
            "opacity": 0
        });
    }
});
```

this code is working perfectly, but after first click I am using "mouseleave" event to hide sub items but what I need is to convert "mouseleave" event to second click. 
can some one give me a guide to do this?

Comment: On click, check for a variable. If it isn't true, set it to true. Next time you click, it will be true and you can do whatever you want next.

Comment: ... or alternatively remove the first event listener at the end of its handler, and attach another one.

Comment: Alternatively you could google "toggle event replacement". You should find event a simple plugin that implements the old toggle event.

Answer (score 0):

Now I'm using this jquery code but still there is little problem, that is when I click on parent item it is showing the sub items and if I click on a sub item it is showing the child items. but and if I click again on a sub item it is hiding those child items but the problem is I can't make it to hide sub items when I click second time on  sub items.

this is not a big issue so I think this is good so I'm positng this as my answer but if some one can figure it out to hide sub items also it will be good for me.

var $showing_sub = 0;
var $showing_child = 0;

```
$(function() {
    $('.parent').click(function() {
        if ($showing_sub == 0) {
            $sub_itmes = $('.subperent', this);
            $sub_itmes.css({
                "display": "block",
            });
            $sub_itmes.animate({
                "opacity": 1
            });
        }
        else
        {
            $sub_itmes = $('.subperent', this);
            $sub_itmes.css({
                "display": "none",
            });
            $sub_itmes.animate({
                "opacity": 0
            });
            $showing_sub = 0;
        }
    });
});

$(function() {
    $('.subperent').click(function() {
        if ($showing_child == 0) {
            $sub_itmes = $('.chilld', this);
            $sub_itmes.css({
                "display": "block",
            });
            $sub_itmes.animate({
                "opacity": 1
            });

            $showing_child = 1;
            //$showing_sub = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            $sub_itmes = $('.chilld', this);
            $sub_itmes.css({
                "display": "none",
            });
            $sub_itmes.animate({
                "opacity": 0
            });
            $showing_child = 0;

        }
    });
});
```